# How do I embed a link to a reply in a telegram message?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to build a bot that sends messages which embed a couple of standard replies which can be sent just by tapping on them.

Each link would contain a space - e.g. "/ack 20134" & "/pass 20134"

So tapping on the first link causes the text "/ack 20134" to be sent back to the bot.

How do I embed this into the message that I send from the bot to the client in text, HTML or Markup?

Answer (score 1):

set that element (button text for example) `text` field to "/ack 20134" .Then when user hit the button this command will send to your bot. you can use `inline keyboards` and set its `data` in`callback_data` to this value. But you cannont use it a text message because space separates two fields(embeds just "/ack" i.e. command part. user can hit it but your bot just receives "/ack".)

For text messages there is another option: do not use space(e.g. "/ack20134" without space) and your bot's would receive "/ack20134", then you must parse commands part)

Comment: The first point here is that anything preceded by a "/" becomes a link even in plain text (I hadn't checked that).

The rest becomes common sense.

Thank you.